Determinant of the matrix $I+A+A^2+ \cdots + A^{n-1}$.
Let $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ be real numbers and let $A = (a_{i,j})_{n\times n}$ the matrix defined by $a_{i,i+1} = c_i$ for each $i = 1,2, \ldots, n-1$, $a_{n,1} = c_{n}$ and the other entries are zero. Show that the determinant of the matrix $I+A+A^2+ \cdots + A^{n-1}$ is equal to $(1-c)^{n-1}$ where $c = c_1c_2\cdots c_n$
I've tried to find a pattern with the determinant of the $A^n$ matrices or something. I can't find this excercise o similar in the textbooks I have seen.

Hint: $X^n - 1 = (X - 1)(X^{n - 1} + \dots + X + 1)$.

Please calculate $$  \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & a \
b & 0 \
\end{array}
\right)^2
$$   and $$  \left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & a & 0\
0& 0&b  \
c&0&0 \end{array}
\right)^3
$$  and  $$  \left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & a & 0&0\
0& 0&b &0 \
0&0&0&c \ d & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}
\right)^4
$$

One can see that $A^n$ is a diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries are equal to $c_1c_2\dots c_n=c$.
Therefore, $det(A^n-1)=(c-1)^n$. Moreover, we have $A^n-1=(A-1)(I+A+\dots+A^{n-1})$. This gives $det(A^n-1)=det((A-1))det((I+A+\dots+A^{n-1}))$.
Also it can be seen that, $det(A-I)=c-1$. This completes the answer.
